# Are there any benefits of using Apache's mod_cache_disk with Magento 2?

Tags: magento2, magento-1.9, cache, optimization, apache2

I'm currently configuring a web hosting server (Ubuntu 16, Apache 2.4, 8GB RAM, 6 Core CPU) with about 20 Wordpress and Magento 1.9.X/2.2.X sites and would like to optimize it for speed with Apache's mod_cache_disk.

But I'm not sure if there are any benefits or possible side effects of using mod_cache_disk with Magento.

I noticed some side effects for the Wordpress sites, for example the browser shows a page which isn't requested, but for Magento I'm not seeing any issues at the moment.

The current Magento vhosts/htaccess file has this caching configuration:

```
CacheQuickHandler off
CacheLock on
CacheLockPath /tmp/mod_cache-lock
CacheLockMaxAge 5
CacheIgnoreHeaders Set-Cookie
<Location />
    CacheEnable disk
    CacheHeader on
    CacheDefaultExpire 600
    CacheMaxExpire 86400
    CacheLastModifiedFactor 0.5
</Location>
```

My questions are:

- are there any benefits of using Apache's disk cache with Magento 1.9.X or 2.2.X or is this counterproductive because of Magento's native caching system?
- are there any possible issues to watch out for if using this combination?

Also any general tips and experiences regarding this, would be appreciated.

*Btw, I know that the recommended performance optimization for Magento is (in short) Nginx, Varnish, Redis, Memcached, but I currently don't have the knowledge nor the resources to configure this (although I am enthusiastic to do it one day).*

Answer (score 1):

do not use this cache for apache.

**best option:**

for wordpress and magento 1 install Varnish extension.
in magento 2 varnish cache already built in. use Varnish cache and SSD disk.

**second option:**

if you dont know how to configure varnish, just install cache extension:
for wordpress you can try this one:
https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-fastest-cache/

for magento 1 you can use this one:
https://github.com/GordonLesti/Lesti_Fpc

in magento 2 just use `production` mode.

> p.s. cache must be managed/controlled by application, thats why you
>   have to install special extensions.

Comment: +1 for Lesti FPC, didn't know about it and will definitely give it a try for the M1 sites. But this doesn't really answer my question... You wrote not to use apache's disk cache, could you explain why?

Comment: read p.s. note, also if you really need some useful cache - install google pagespeed module https://www.modpagespeed.com/